# How to run a sed command to take in a sed file and output a sql file

Tags: sql, linux, unix, ubuntu, sed

Updated Problem: http://pastebin.com/SrVC8PvW:

Sed File — `csv2sql.sed`:

```
s|\([A-Z]*\),\([A-Z]*\),\([A-Za-z0-9’ ()\.\!-]*\),\([A-Za-z0-9’ ()\.\!-]*\),\([0-9]*\)|INSERT INTO `Schedule` (`ID`,`YEAR`,`NUMBER`,`TeamR1`,`TeamR2`, `TeamR3`, `TeamB1`, `TeamB2`, `TeamB3`) VALUES ('\1', '\2', '\3', '\4', '\5', '\6', '\7', '\8', '\9');|g
```

CSV File (part of it):

```
1,2015,0,57,3310,3676,624,3802,3481
```

Console Error:

```
sed: file csv2sql.sed line 1: invalid reference \9 on `s` command's RHS
```

I have a SED file called csv2sql.sed and it will take in a CSV file and output it to a SQL syntax. I want to run the script, and have a *new* sql file called schedules.sql in the same folder.

How do I fix the error I'm getting?

Comment: `man sed`. You'll get the answer faster than you typed this question.

Comment: or at least edit your question with small sample input, expected output, and current output including any error messages (exact text). Good luck.

Comment: The `sed` file captures `\1` to `\5` so references to `\6`, `\7`, `\8` and `\9` are wrong.  That's what the error message said, really.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what do you do about 6-9?

Comment: Either add more captures to the left side of the `s///` regex, or not reference them on the right side of it (even when it is a `s|||` command).  If you must do it with `sed`, you have to write this stuff out.  You'd probably do better with `awk`, which could split on commas reasonably reliably (unless there are embedded commas in any of the fields — that gives a headache with `sed` too), or with a language with 'proper' support for CSV format data: Perl has a Text::CSV module that you can install, and Python comes with a CSV module that you can use.

Comment: I got it to work, it doesnt include the INSERT INTO `Schedule` part: http://pastebin.com/pqeCVYHG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you sed file is correct (I doubt that), then you would run

```
sed -f csv2sql.sed xxx.dat > schedules.sql
```

where xxx.dat is the file containing your csv data.

Schedules.sql will be created in your current working directory.

Answer (score 2):

<sup>*This would be comments but it is too convoluted for presentation in a comment any more, so it becomes an answer.*</sup>

The `sed` script sets up 5 captures, and then tries to reference captures 1-9.  The error message is telling you that you can't refer to what you didn't capture.

The original `sed` script appears to be:

```
s|\([A-Z]*\),\([A-Z]*\),\([A-Za-z0-9' ()\.\!-]*\),\([A-Za-z0-9' ()\.\!-]*\),\([0-9]*\)|INSERT INTO `Schedule` (`ID`,`YEAR`,`NUMBER`,`TeamR1`,`TeamR2`, `TeamR3`, `TeamB1`, `TeamB2`, `TeamB3`) VALUES ('\1', '\2', '\3', '\4', '\5', '\6', '\7', '\8', '\9');|g
```

The 'matching' part of that is:

```
|\([A-Z]*\),\([A-Z]*\),\([A-Za-z0-9' ()\.\!-]*\),\([A-Za-z0-9' ()\.\!-]*\),\([0-9]*\)|
  ^          ^          ^                         ^                         ^
  1          2          3                         4                         5
```

The sample data appears to be 9 integers separated by commas.  This doesn't appear to bear much resemblance to the column titles used, but that's probably a separate discussion.  If the CSV data is simple enough that it does not contain either commas or single quotes (in this case) within fields, then you can handle it more simply with:

```
s|\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)|INSERT … VALUES ('\1', '\2', '\3', '\4', '\5', '\6', '\7', '\8', '\9');|
```

If your version of `sed` supports EREs (extended regular expressions), you can simplify that to:

```
s|([^,]*\),([^,]*\),([^,]*\),([^,]*\),([^,]*\),([^,]*\),([^,]*\),([^,]*\),([^,]*\)|INSERT … VALUES ('\1', '\2', '\3', '\4', '\5', '\6', '\7', '\8', '\9');|
```

You might need to use `-r` (GNU `sed`) or `-E` (BSD `sed`) to enable EREs.

This gets you around the technical problem in the `sed` script.  It is a gruesome way to deal with the data.  For the sample data, you could use `awk` to process the lines:

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { i1 = "INSERT INTO `Schedule` (`ID`,`YEAR`,`NUMBER`"
                 i2 = ",`TeamR1`,`TeamR2`, `TeamR3`, `TeamB1`,"
                 i3 = "`TeamB2`, `TeamB3`) VALUES"
               }
         NF==9 {printf "%s%s%s('%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');\n",
                       i1, i2, i3, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9 }
        '
```

There are numerous other ways to deal with this in `awk`, with loops etc.

If you really need to deal with CSV data, then use a language that understands CSV data.  For example, Perl has [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text%3A%3ACSV) (but it usually has to be installed as an extra) and Python has its [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?) module installed as standard.  Either of these will make it easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

You can run like this

```
sed -f csv2sql.sed tes1.csv
```

CSV:

```
ABC,ABC,AbC9).,AbC9).,98
```

Output:

```
INSERT INTO `Schedule` (`F1`,`F2`,`F3`,`F4`,`F5`) VALUES ('ABC', 'ABC', 'AbC9).', 'AbC9).', '98');
```

csv2sql.sed looks like this

```
s|\([A-Z]*\),\([A-Z]*\),\([A-Za-z0-9’ ()\.\!-]*\),\([A-Za-z0-9’ ()\.\!-]*\),\([0-9]*\)|INSERT INTO `Schedule` (`F1`,`F2`,`F3`,`F4`,`F5`) VALUES ('\1', '\2', '\3', '\4', '\5');|g
```

Answer (score 0):

I would NOT use `sed` for this.  It seems VERY likely that the **csv** module in the Python standard library can parse your input with far less coding on your part and far more robustly than anything you're going to write in `sed`.

Here's a simple program which will read a CSV file such as you've described, assuming you have a header line matching your list of column names (quoted literally as you want it to appear in your SQL) and write it into a series of INSERT INTO statements as you've described:

```
#!python
# For Python version 2.x > 2.6
import csv, sys
form = 'INSERT INTO `Schedule` {0} VALUES ({1});\n'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_args = len(sys.argv[1:])
    if num_args < 1:
        print >> sys.stderr, "Must supply input filename"
        sys.exit(1)

    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        header = next(reader)
        data = list()
        for row in reader:
            data.append(row)

    with open('./csvdata.sql', 'w') as outfile:
        for each in data:
            outfile.write(form.format(', '.join(header), ', '.join(each)))
```

With only a little extra work you could add support for command line arguments for input and output filenames and turn this into a general purpose utility for generating SQL INSERT statement for any CSV with an appropriate header line (where you could specify the table into which you insert using a command line option).

With slightly more effort you could omit the header and have a bit of Python dynamically pull the list of column names from database (execute a query like `SELECT * FROM`sometable`WHERE 1=0` through any Python DBAPI driver and read the result set objects `.description` attribute).

I only separated this into two separate loops for expository simplicity ... merge the `outfile.write()` into the first loop to obviate the `data.append` and you can handle arbitrarily large files constant memory overhead.

Add the SQL handling directly and figure out how to use `.executemany()` and you can perform the operation (CSV -> your SQL RDBMS) in one pass, without the intermediary .sql text file.  (Do to that you'd also probably have to add some type handling in the CSV reading loop).  However, that's likely to operate for more efficiently than a text file of single SQL INSERT statements.  (Portions of these Python DBAPI drivers may be in platform native C binary rather than executing through Python dispatch for each row in the `.executemany()`, for example).

Here's a version of the script suitable for Python 3.x and implementing slightly improved argument handling.  Here the output file is the first argument and all other arguments are input files:

```
#!python
#!/usr/bin/env python3
## Python 3.x
import csv, sys

usage='%s outfile infile [infile2 ...]' % sys.argv[0]

form = 'INSERT INTO `Schedule` {0} VALUES ({1});\n'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_args = len(sys.argv[1:])
    if num_args < 1:
        print ("Must supply input filename", file=sys.stderr)
        sys.exit(1)

    data = list()
    for each in sys.argv[2:]:
        try:
            with open(each, 'r') as infile:
                reader = csv.reader(infile)
                header = next(reader)
                for row in reader:
                    data.append(row)
        except EnvironmentError as e:
            print('Warning %s: unable to read data from %s' % (e, each), file=sys.stderr)

    try:
        with open(sys.argv[1], 'w') as outfile:
            for each in data:
                outfile.
```

write(form.format(', '.join(header), ', '.join(each)))
        except EnvironmentError as e:
            print('Error: %s: unable to write results to %s' % (e, sys.argv[1], file=sys.stderr)
            sys.exit(1)

This version also adds very simple exception handling around the file I/O reading input errors as "Warnings" and any output error as a error.

Comment: Where would the myinput.csv be located at @Jim Dennis? Also, what is the r and w for?

Comment: In my example I hard-coded ./myinput.csv as the filename.  You could replace that with anything you like.  I'll edit the example so you could supply it on the command line.

Comment: `AttributeError: '_csv.reader' object has no attribute 'next'
`

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  It works for my copy of 2.7.9; and none of what I'm doing has changed since 2.6 at the latest?

Comment: 3.4 < Just installed it like an hour ago :P

Comment: Just double checked @JimDennis, i have 3.4 (Most recent Version) (Windows 64x)

Comment: So it is a difference between Python2.x and Python3.x.  I used reader.next() because generators and iterators in Python2.x implement their iteration using that method.  Under Python3.x this was changed to .__next__() to be more consistent with other "special" (dunder === "double underscore") methods.

The more portable method would be to call the 'next()' builtin function which works across these versions (going back to Python 2.6).

I've changed the code to reflect that and added a whole different version to run under Python3.x and handle command line arguments a little better in general.